# Sending a mail to users,when data is uploaded from a csv file into database

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I have a import.php file which imports the data from a csv file into the database. The code for import.php is given below

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include_once "auth.php";
include 'common.php';
if(($_SESSION['SESS_CATEGORY']=='requestor') AND ($_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_DEPT'] != 'TXN')){
    header("location: menu.php");
        exit();
}
echo '<ul style = "margin-top: -9px;"">
 <li style="margin-left: 550px; list-style: none;" align ="center"><a href="menu.php"><font size = "2" face="verdana">GO BACK TO MENU</font></a></li></ul>';
if(!$link){
    die( "Sorry! There seems to be a problem connecting to our database.");
}
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return end(explode('.',$file_name));
}
function errors($error){
    if (!empty($error))
    {
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < count($error)){
            $showError= '<div class="msg-error">'.$error[$i].'</div>';
            $i ++;}
            return $showError;
    }
}
$to ="*TXN_PlanningTNC@gmail.com";
$subject = "TND uploaded";
$message = "New TND(s) uploaded,please check TXN portal for details.";
$user_name = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
if (isset($_POST['upfile'])) {
    if(get_file_extension($_FILES["uploaded"]["name"])!= 'csv')
    {
        echo '<p align="center">Only CSV files accepted!';
        return false;
    }
    $tot = 0;
    $handle = fopen($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"], "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {
            if($data[0] !=''){
                mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO new_tnds(`TND_ID`,`Site_name_S1`,`Site_name_S2`,`Call_sign_S1`,`Idea_ID_S1`,`Call_sign_S2`,`Idea_ID_S2`,`Site_to_integrate`,`True_azimuth_S1`,`True_azimuth_S2`,`Path_length_(km)`,`TR_Antenna_diameter_(m)_S1`,`TR_Antenna_diameter_(m)_S2`,`TR_Antenna_height_(m)_S1`,`TR_Antenna_height_(m)_S2`,`#1_Channel_ID_S1`,`#1_Channel_ID_S2`,`#1_Design_frequency_S1`,`#1_Design_frequency_S2`,`Polarization`,`Radio_model_S1`,`Radio_model_S2`,`TX_power_(dBm)_S1`,`TX_power_(dBm)_S2`,`Receive_signal_(dBm)_S1`,`Receive_signal_(dBm)_S2`,`cluster`)VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[0])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[1])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[2])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[3])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[4])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[5])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[6])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[7])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[8])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[9])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[10])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[11])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[12])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[13])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[14])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[15])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[16])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[17])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[18])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[19])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[20])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[21])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[22])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[23])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[24])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[25])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data[26])."')")or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
                    $sql ="UPDATE new_tnds SET  TND_uploadedtime = now() where TND_ID = '$data[0]'";
                    $sql1 ="UPDATE new_tnds SET TND_uploaded_user_name = '$user_name' where TND_ID = '$data[0]'";
                    if (mysqli_query($link,$sql))
                    {
                        if (mysqli_query($link,$sql1))
                        {
                            echo '';
                        }
                    }
            }
            else{
                    echo '<p align="center">check the data in the csv file!';
                }

            $tot++;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $content= '<div class="success" id="message"> CSV File Imported, $tot records added </div>';
}
if(TND_uploadedtime = )
echo "<h3 align = 'center'>Import CSV Data</h3>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post' align = 'center'>
    File:<input name='uploaded' type='file' maxlength='20' accept='.csv'/><input type='submit' name='upfile' value='Upload File'>
    <p>Don't upload more than 500 TNDs at a time.</p>
</form>";
?>
```

I want to trigger mail when ever that data gets uploaded.So i have function for the mail which sends mail to the concerned people.I have uploaded time as one of the columns in the import file itself. Can anyone suggest me how to capture that uploaded event and trigger that mail function.

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($to,$subject,$message, $files)
{

//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: txnportal.tnc@idea.adityabirla.com\r\nReply-To: txnportal.tnc@idea.adityabirla.com";

if($files[0]!="NULL")
{
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($files[0])));
$name = basename($files[0]);


//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $message; ?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/zip; name=<?php echo $name; ?> 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--


<?php
$message.= ob_get_clean();

}
else
{

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
}
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer

//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"

return $mail_sent;

}
?>
```